# Code highlighting js that would work with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, browserify, browserify-shim

I am looking for a code highlighter that would support main coding languages (sass/scss also) and would work nicely with Browserify.

At the moment I was using [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/), it works just nice (as highlighter), but I cannot seem to make it work with Browserify. Recently, I started using Browserify (which is awesome) and works fine with all scripts and modules, except highlighter (which I need).

Is there a good code highlighter that works fluently with Browserify without major hacking? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prismjs works now seamlessly with browserify.

```js
const Prism = require('prismjs');
Prism.highlightAll();
```

This would basically do the same as using the script tag version.

Answer (score 0):

[highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) is another popular choice that boasts Node compatibility as a selling-point. But I think [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) is nicer, both visually and in terms of filesize.

It's still possible to use Prism in Browserify, just not as an NPM module we can require directly. Download the script and save it somewhere relative to your main JS file:

```
javascript/
├── vendor/
├── └── prism.js
└── main.js
```

Then `require` it from your entry-point JS file (`main.js` above) without variable assignment:

```
// Pretty code! :D
require('./vendor/prism');
```

If you've set up Browserify's `paths` option, you might not need the leading `./` in that filepath.